# Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs Filter Issue - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to find the top 5 newest sign-in logs for the specified user within the last 30 days. The user's email is pg0011111@contoso.com.

The following command worked when filtering by date only, this would get all of the sign-in logs on or after 2023-04-01:

```
"Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt 2023-04-01""
```

However, when I combined it with the user principal name filter as shown below, it didn't work:

```
$auditLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt 2023-04-01 and UserPrincipalName -eq 'pg0011111@contoso.com'" -Top 5
```

This command only retrieves the newest sign-in logs for the last 24 hours, whereas the specified user's most recent log-in was 3 days ago.

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue, but so far I haven't been successful. Could someone please assist me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Another cool way to achieve that is using the beta endpoint of the Graph API.
You can use the Microsoft.Graph.Beta PS module, like I do in this example.
Through the beta endpoint a new user property is available - "signInActivity".
SignInActivity gives you the most recent interactive and non-interactive sign in.

```
PS /Users/josuadoering/repos> $user = Get-MgBetaUser -UserId 'acbfdf10-0c41-458a-82f0-22385dca69e9' -Property UserPrincipalName,SignInActivity
PS /Users/josuadoering/repos> $user.SignInActivity                                                                                            

LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime LastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId    LastSignInDateTime    LastSignInRequestId
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------    ------------------    -------------------
4/19/2023 2:06:42 PM             eeea6682-aebb-47e9-b2df-2df41c102300 4/19/2023 10:22:15 AM 9047e3ab-b786-4f52-ad63-c69696920500
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To get the **Audit Sign In Logs of the user within 30 days**, try the below script:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString("2023-03-16")
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString("2023-04-17")
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate and UserPrincipalName eq 'admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'"
```

[image]

To get the **top 5 newest sign-in logs for the specified user within the last 30 days** use the below script:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString("2023-03-16")
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString("2023-04-17")
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime ge $startDate and createdDateTime le $endDate and UserPrincipalName eq 'admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'" | Select-Object -First 5
```

[image]